# running command in loop by properties file Shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to run git command to to create new branch,
The command is:

```
git checkout -b branch1.00 branch1.00
```

Now I want to run this command when instead of **"branch1.00"** I will have a parameter (lets call it **$branch**) , this parameter will take it's value from a .properties file (lets call that file  **prop.properties**) and run this command on all values in this file.

So if the prop.properties file will look like that:

```
branch=branch1.00
branch=branch2.00
branch=branch3.00
branch=branch4.00
```

The git command will run 4 times like that:

```
git checkout -b branch1.00 branch1.00
git checkout -b branch2.00 branch2.00
git checkout -b branch3.00 branch3.00
git checkout -b branch4.00 branch4.00
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `while` loop with do the job:

```
while IFS='=' read -r _ b; do
   git checkout -b "$b" "$b"
done < prop.properties
```

If there is no `branch=` prefix then use:

```
while read -r b; do
   git checkout -b "$b" "$b"
done < prop.properties
```

This will run these commands:

```
git checkout -b branch1.00 branch1.00
git checkout -b branch2.00 branch2.00
git checkout -b branch3.00 branch3.00
git checkout -b branch4.00 branch4.00
```

Comment: Great!!!
Works!! the only thing I had to change is removing the "branch=" in the beginning of the properties file